# My question:When I started my website, the "page not found" error always came up

Tags: 404-error, homepage, home-url

[image]

I make sure my .htaccess is set to default and I try to install a freshly new WordPress but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but if you go to `settings` -> `permalinks` and use the standard (ugly) permalinks with all the variables in the url it maybe will work.

If it works, you probably don't have `mod_rewite` installed on your server. And you can't use the "pretty" url's.